# How to check uniqueness of multiple fields but checked individually in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, constraints, uniq

I have a situation where I need to combine multiple fields to check uniqueness but the uniqueness needs to be checked individually. For instance,

1. (A, 1) - should pass and successfully inserted
2. (B, 2) - should pass and successfully inserted
3. (B, 1) - should fail since there is a '1' already
4. (A, 2) - should fail since there is a '2' already

Setting unique for both fields does not prohibit (3) and (4) from being inserted since uniqueness checks both fields. I cannot make these two fields as primary keys since I have a rich schema and there is already an unique UUID as the primary key.

Comment: Would a unique constraint suffice? `CREATE TABLE t (c1 TEXT, c2 TEXT UNIQUE );`? If the table already exists: `ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT un_c2 UNIQUE (c2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, add indiviual unique constraints to your columns, e.g.

Data Sample:

```
CREATE TABLE t 
(c1 TEXT UNIQUE, 
 c2 INT  UNIQUE);
```

These inserts will work .

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('A',1),('B',2);

INSERT 0 2
```

.. and these will fail

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('B',1);

ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "t_c1_key"
DETAIL:  Key (c1)=(B) already exists.

INSERT INTO t VALUES ('A',2);

ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "t_c1_key"
DETAIL:  Key (c1)=(A) already exists.
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4d0c793042b3025a02c923577ae64df0)

Answer (score 0):

You need two `UNIQUE` constraints, one on each column.

Different from primary keys, you can have several unique constraints on a table. To get the same behavior as a primary key, set the columns `NOT NULL`.